# How can write a smart contract for my use case in Hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, smartcontracts

i want to write a smart contract (logic.js)for my use case using hyperledger composer playground tool, i know it is writen in javascript so i studied it(javascript), also i read examples for smart contracts for other networks but it is not enough to me to write my own one, also i read this link( https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/reference/js_scripts.html). but it still not enough, so my question is how can write my own (logig.js )file?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to learn the JavaScript. Then doing something practical like https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles .This is an open source project. Hope it helpfull.